# Which object exactly cause "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"?

Tags: exception, c#-3.0, object-reference

I have DLL that run on server and I can't debug it for many reasons, I log its exceptions.
sometimes I have `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"` in a method call that have about 20 parameter that take from me long time to know where's the object that cause the exception.

**Is there any way to log the exception in case of `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"` with the name of the object that cause the exception ?**

Comment: Having methods with 20 parameters is a bad idea in any case ...

Comment: it isn't the main problem, as even i have the same problem in a method wih 6 parameter  ...

Comment: If you are having this problem in multiple places then @Andrew Hare's answer below is what you want to listen to.  You need to program more defensively because code is passing in null arguments when you don't expect them to be null.  That means you have to be more careful with calling code or you can't trust calling code the way you think you can.  This error is a symptom of a larger problem in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to *log* the exact argument that was null (it sounds like debugging is out of the question) you will need to test each parameter individually for null and throw an [`ArgumentNullException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception.aspx) for that parameter if it is null with the name of the parameter passed as a string to the [exception's constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8a0dfcy.aspx).

This is one reason (among many) that a method accepting 20 parameters can lead to tough maintenance issues.  It indicates that a method may have too many responsibilities and may be trying to do more than it should.  While you are in the code you might want to consider breaking this method up into smaller pieces.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the line where the exception happens, you could disassemble the assembly with [Redgate .NET Reflector Free](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/index.htm) the get more information!

otherwise: no, there's no chance to get the parameter-name, which caused an exception, except there's an argumentException (where the name of the parameter is included in the exception)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to determine what object is causing this is to attach the debugger to whatever code you have running.  You probably will need to run a separate server running the code built in debug mode.  In Visual Studio if you go into the Debug -> Exceptions... menu item you will have a dialog of exception types with two columns.  Check the Thrown column for Common Language Runtime Exceptions.  Then try the operation where the exception is being thrown.  That's the easiest way what object is causing the problem.

Another thing you can try to see if there are any side affects being caused by this error appearing and back trace it from there.

You also could print the whole stack trace for the error instead of just the error message.  That might give you the detail you need.